# How to intercept method calls in C#

Tags: c#, .net, autoit-c#-wrapper

I'd like to intercept and inject custom code when calling 3rd party code in C#. I am using an external library (AutoIt) for GUI automation. The AutoIt dll is provided without source code.

All actions done with this framework are performed from a single class (`AutoItClass`) providing access to all the methods. I'd like to be able to inject custom code when calling methods on this class, is this possible? For example:

1. Log some information from within the called method.
2. Perform any other action from within the method (wait for X seconds).

This would be possible very simply by inheriting from this class and overriding *all* its methods (which is a must since this is a COM object), but this is not the preferred way. Any comments will be helpful!

Comment: This is called Aspect Oriented Programming (or AOP) -- something that is not well supported currently by many programming languages. You'll need compiler support to inject your calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use inheritance - you can use composition here. Create your own class which has the same methods - or in fact only the ones you're interested in - and delegate through that. That way you can be sure you won't "miss" any methods accidentally, because anything you don't implement won't be callable through the rest of your codebase... so long as you make sure the rest of your code doesn't refer to the original library class, of course.

Comment: This still involved alot of manual work. Isn't there any framework that allows saying: WhenCalled(autoit.ClickButton, PerformThisMethod);

Comment: @liortal: You could autogenerate the code pretty easily. If the class implemented an interface, you could use the .NET DynamicProxy class. If the class methods are virtual, you could use the Castle project's dynamic proxy support. Without either of those being the case, I don't think there's anything simpler than generating a facade.

Comment: @jonskeet What is the .NET DynamicProxy class? i failed to find anything like this built into the framework itself.

Comment: @liortal: My mistake, it's called RealProxy (terrible name).

Comment: a comment on generation. `Resharper` allows easily implementing such delegating methods. `Alt+Ins` -> `Delegating members` (or smth like that)

Comment: I've heard of some mocking frameworks that have similar features, does anybody know of any ? is it possible to do this way?

Comment: @liortal: TypeMock will do this, I believe - but it's really designed for mocking for tests. Why are you resisting the simpler approach so much? By now you could easily have had a decorator class working...

Comment: The problem with wrapping the original code is that i would have to insert the same piece of code to around 30 methods, which could get un-maintainable pretty quickly...

Comment: @liortal: If it's the same code, you could autogenerate that reasonably easily. It's a pain to start with, but easy to *maintain* I'd have thought... how often are you really going to change what you're doing, in a way which can't be encapsulated in a simple method (thus creating *one* point to change instead of 30)?

Comment: I'm doing a GUI automation util, i'd like to be able to log each method call to the underlying GUI automation provider (AutoIT), insert random/exact wait time before each button press. Do you think it would be wise to insert this logic to every method i'm overriding?

Comment: @liortal: Sounds to me like you can do all of that with a single helper method which you call from each method.

Answer (score 3):

You can investigate [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/monitoring#tracing), which is a commercial product that can inject IL into compiled assemblies to perform [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). You can define different kind of behaviour that should happen before and after a method gets executed, for example, which seems to be what you want. This way, as PostSharp handles this in a post-compilation step, you don't need to create any inherited classes from the classes that you want to intercept.

Otherwise if you want a more "pure" solution I would follow Jon's advice about creating a new class that wraps the functionality of the one that you want to intercept. (see [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)) .